# Django: serialize QuerySet and send it to template to be used with Javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I've a QuerySet and I need to send it to my template, because I need to manipulate its values to generate a JS array.

But when in my view I use:

```
 order_items = json.dumps(order_items)
```

I get:

```
Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable
```

**view:**

```
import json

def thanks_deposit_payment(request):

    order_number = Order.objects.latest('id').id
    total = Order.objects.latest('id').total
    costo_despacho = Order.objects.latest('id').shipping_cost
    order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=Order.objects.latest('id'))
    # order_items = json.dumps(order_items)

    response = render(request, 'thanks_deposit_payment.html', dict(order_number=order_number, total=total,
                                                                   order_items=order_items, costo_despacho=costo_despacho))
    return response
```

**models.py**:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name= 'PEN Price')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files', blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "OrderItem"
```

**I need to generate the products array using the items in order_items send from backend:**

```
 <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            event: 'eec.purchase',
            ecommerce: {
                currencyCode: 'PEN',
                purchase: {
                    actionField: {
                        id: {{ order_number }},
                        affiliation: 'Stickers Gallito E-Commerce',
                        revenue: {{ total }},
                        shipping: {{ costo_despacho }},
                        coupon: 'SUMMER2019'
                    }
                },
                products: [

    {% for item in order_items %}
                  {
                    id: item.order.id,
                    name: item.product,
                    price: item.price,
                    size: item.size,
                    quantity: item.quantity
                  },
    {% endfor %}
                ]
            }
        });
    </script>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Using ruddras answer, I'm doing:

```
def thanks_deposit_payment(request):
    order_number = Order.objects.latest('id').id

    total = Order.objects.latest('id').total

    costo_despacho = Order.objects.latest('id').shipping_cost

    order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=Order.objects.latest('id'))
    order_items = json.dumps(serialize('json', order_items))

    response = render(request, 'thanks_deposit_payment.html', dict(order_number=order_number, total=total,
                                                                   order_items=order_items, costo_despacho=costo_despacho))
    return response
```

But getting Error:

> VM1835:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position
>   0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at (index):55

In **thanks_deposit_payment.html**:

```
{% block data_layer %}

<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
        event: 'eec.purchase',
        ecommerce: {
            currencyCode: 'PEN',
            purchase: {
                actionField: {
                    id: {{ order_number }},
                    affiliation: 'Stickers Gallito E-Commerce',
                    revenue: {{ total }},
                    shipping: {{ costo_despacho }},
                    coupon: 'SUMMER2019'
                }
            },
            products: JSON.parse('{{ order_items }}')
        }
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Console Tab in Chrome's Web Developer Tools:

```
VM2315:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at (index):55
```

Sources Tab (Line 55):

```
products: JSON.parse('[{&quot;model&quot;: &quot;order.orderitem&quot;, &quot;pk&quot;: 8, &quot;fields&quot;: {&quot;product&quot;: &quot;Sobre con muestras&quot;, &quot;price&quot;: &quot;3.00&quot;}}]')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Django JSON Serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json) to convert queryset to JSON String:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=Order.objects.latest('id'))
order_items = serialize('json', order_items, fields=['id', 'product', 'price'])  # the fields needed for products
```

Then use it in template:

```
 products: JSON.parse('{{ order_items | safe }}')
```

Comment: may you expand on how to generate the products array? ty.

Comment: Don't understand how could I loop in the template with  products: `JSON.parse('{{ order_items }}')`. Also where does JSON come from in template? Do I need to call some library?

Comment: basically you are sending the value as context. And you are already sending the data in json format. You are using `<script>` tag, I am assuming that is in `thanks_deposit_payment.html` template. When sending the value of order_items, I already converted them to a List of dictionaries. So no need to loop through them. You can directly put the value as `products: JSON.parse('{{ order_items }}')`. Also used JSON.parse to convert the string value to Json in Javascript

Comment: Please, see update 1. I'm surely missunderstanding some part.

Comment: please remove `json.dumps()` from your code. My answer contains the implementation you need :)

Comment: Did, but now seeing a different error :(. See update 2 pls. I've also posted the OrderItem model in the original question.

Comment: Can you please try with `JSON.parse('{{ order_items | safe }}')`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def thanks_deposit_payment(request):
 order_number = Order.objects.latest('id').id
 total = Order.objects.latest('id').total
 costo_despacho = Order.objects.latest('id').shipping_cost
 order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=Order.objects.latest('id'))

 return JSONResponse(...here goes the dict with all data to send to view)
```

Even, you can send a dict inside a dict if you want to send all this queryset.)
Later, I recommend you to use AJAX with JQuery.